# ¿Se puede detectar la pulsación de una tecla en un elemento con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

para detectar una tecla en con jQuery en todo el documento es así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").keydown(function(tecla){
   if(tecla.which == 8){
      alert('Has presionado la tecla BACKSPACE');
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Presiona la tecla BACKSPACE 
</h1>
```

pero me gustaría que al clicar en un elemento me detecte el BACKSPACE pero no me funciona.¿Porque será?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#calendar #dias td").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 8){
  alert("Has presionado la tecla BACKSPACE");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table tr td{
 border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calendar">
<tr id="dias">
<td>celda 1</td>
<td>celda 2</td>
<td>celda 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En elementos que tengan foco si se puede. En td me da que no.

Comment: Onfocus="function() "?

Answer (score 0):

He probado de hacer esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function presionar_tecla(tecla){
          if (tecla.which == 8) {
            alert("Has presionado la tecla      BACKSPACE");
          }
  }
});
```

```css
table tr td{
 border: solid 1px black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calendar">
<tr id="dias">
<td onfocus="presionar_tecla(tecla)">celda 1</td>
<td onfocus="presionar_tecla(tecla)">celda 2</td>
<td onfocus="presionar_tecla(tecla)">celda 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Y no me funciona,¿Querías decir esto?

Comment: Eso no va a funcionar porque necesitas 2 eventos, el de pulsar y el del foco. En el evento del foco no vas a tener tecla pulsada.

Answer (score 0):

Como te ha comentado JDev detectar eventos de teclado solo se puede hacer en elementos que puedan tener el foco, y `td` no es uno de ellos, se me ocurre que podrías hacer que los `td` tengan `inputs` para poder detectar eventos de teclado. Por cierto ¿porque quieres detectar eventos de teclado en un `td`?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".input").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 8){
  alert("Has presionado la tecla BACKSPACE");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table tr td{
 border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calendar">
<tr id="dias">
  <td><input type="text" class="input" value="Celda 1"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input" value="Celda 2"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input" value="Celda 3"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```